# What is the format of video produced with WP 8.1?

Tags: video, lumia-925

I need to know the format of video produced by my Nokia Lumia 925 Lumia with WP 8.1.

I know what is supported from the [specifications](http://www.microsoft.com/en/mobile/phone/lumia925/specifications/#head_camera), but what is the format when I record a video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the Lumia camera and the stock camera app record Videos as .mp4 files.

EDIT:
Here are the specs reported by [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/de/MediaInfo) (stripped of all irrelevant data like duration or date and of course some of it depending on settings)

```
General
Format                           : MPEG-4
Format_Profile                   : Base Media / Version 2
CodecID                          : mp42
OverallBitRate/String            : 54.6 Mbps

Video
Format                           : AVC
Format/Info                      : Advanced Video Codec
Format_Profile                   : Main@L5.1
Format_Settings_CABAC/String     : No
Format_Settings_RefFrames/String : 2 frames
CodecID                          : avc1
CodecID/Info                     : Advanced Video Coding
BitRate/String                   : 62.5 Mbps
Width/String                     : 3 840 pixels
Height/String                    : 2 160 pixels
DisplayAspectRatio/String        : 16:9
FrameRate_Mode/String            : Variable
FrameRate/String                 : 24.000 fps
FrameRate_Minimum/String         : 23.810 fps
FrameRate_Maximum/String         : 24.218 fps
ColorSpace                       : YUV
ChromaSubsampling                : 4:2:0
BitDepth/String                  : 8 bits
ScanType/String                  : Progressive
Bits-(Pixel*Frame)               : 0.314
colour_primaries                 : BT.601 NTSC
colour_range                     : Full
mdhd_Duration                    : 2122

Audio
ID/String                        : 2
Format                           : AAC
Format/Info                      : Advanced Audio Codec
Format_Profile                   : LC
CodecID                          : 40
BitRate_Mode/String              : Constant
BitRate/String                   : 192 Kbps
Channel(s)/String                : 1 channel
ChannelPositions                 : Front: C
SamplingRate/String              : 48.0 KHz
Compression_Mode/String          : Lossy
StreamSize/String                : 49.5 KiB (0%)
Source_StreamSize/String         : 49.5 KiB (0%)
```

Comment: It should be noted that a lot of that information (like framerate, bitrate and resolution) will depend on settings in the camera app and isn't constant.

Comment: you're right, I've added that now.

Answer (score 0):

I opened videos recorded with both the stock Camera app as well as Lumia Camera on my Lumia 920 with WP8.1/Denim in VLC player on a PC, and it reported the following codec information for both:

- Video: [H.264 / MPEG-4 AVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC)
- Audio: [MPEG AAC Audio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Audio_Coding)